# Organising Python code

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am newbie learning Python with Java background. As an exercise I want to write an app which calls a web API a bunch of times for all the photos in a specific folder. I have done this using thread pool and currently printing all the json outputs. This is currently two small functions all within one script.

What I want to do is write the JSON to a mongoDB.

Q1: What is the best way to layout my code, should I keep everything in one script within different functions?

Q2: Would you persist to mongoDB in the same thread as the call to the web API (which takes about 30s+ to return) or in a separate thread?

Comment: This really is too broad to answer. However, if you can complete the task in two small functions then it doesn't make sense to separate them into separate files, that adds complexity with no gain in clarity.

Comment: As @roganjosh mentions ... this question is very broad and open to opinion regarding the "best" way to do something >>> what may be best in this case may not be best in other cases.